# Running a Timer on Server

Tags: meteor

I have to code a timer mechanisam. 
The idea is to have it countdown in sec on all clients screen & give the clients an option to increase the countdown period. The timer being common , I assume we need to run it on server.
A few ideas with sample code on Meteor Publish would be great.

Answer (score 1):

- Detect a future time ad get the timestamp
- Save that timestamp on a collection
- Create a simple timer; at each second, get he difference between the current time and the future date and display it (properly converted)
- Create an event that increase the stored future timestamp by N milliseconds; the collection update should be propagated across all clients

Comment: Do I have to update the collection at every second? I set a timer and get the difference and how would I display this from the server to the clients?

Comment: No, the collection Will store a static timestamp. On. The client,run a function at an interval of 1 second and each time get the difference between the stored time and the actual present time